# Python package handling BDDs and ZDDs

Tags: python, combinatorics, enumeration

Is there a python package handling binary decision diagrams (BDDs) and zero suppressed binary decision diagrams (ZDDs), as in Knuth volume 4?

I know networkx can handle DAGs cleanly, but I'm looking for something that handles the internal garbage keeping of ZDDs, constructions from the algebra of set families (Knuth), construction of BDDs from other types of decision diagrams, and maybe some primitive ZDDs and queries (such as sampling and counting).

There are some packages in other languages: [Java](https://elib.uni-stuttgart.de/bitstream/11682/9810/1/thesis.pdf) and [C++](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~alanmi/publications/2001/tech01_zdd_.pdf). (Edits extending this list would be welcome.)

Edit -- several promising tools listed here: https://github.com/johnyf/tool_lists/blob/master/bdd.md

Edit2 -- [Graphillion](https://github.com/takemaru/graphillion), a python package recommended by Minato himself [in this slides](https://si2.epfl.ch/~demichel/si.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/si/files/shared/Logic%20Synthesis%202017/Logic%20Synthesis%202017_Shinichi%20Minato.pdf), may be the canonical answer. Especially as it comes with this endearing [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3Hp9k876Kk) (that comes with this [backstory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4gTV4r0zRs)).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Graphillion should do it.

What's your source of BDD/ZDD? If say for example the source is blif, blif should be translated to x and then the x should be translated to ZDD.

For you, you have to figure out what x is.

Comment: I don't have a convenient representation of the BDD. I can write up the Boolean function pretty easily in a high level language, though. It's complicated by having a graph connectivity subroutine (alternatively a matrix rank routine), but I guess I could in principle convert that into a circuit and then into a .blif ...